# Triangle on a div bottom

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a problem with taking a triangle on a bottom of div, as you can see in image below. This three div's are in flexbox.

HTML code:

```
<section class="main_content">
    <div class="1st_class">
        <div class="features">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            <div class="triangle"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p> 
        </div>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: how it should look like]

Comment: so, what's the problem?

Comment: could you please provide jsfiddle/jsbin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a flexible solution I would recommend using an SVG background image of a triangle and then stretching it across the bottom of the box.

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p49rjx49/) to show what I mean.

```
.active:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -15px;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 15px;
   background-size: 100% 100%;
   background-image: url(triangle.svg);
}
```